# Why is not printf in perl output all arguments? - scalar context seems omitted

Tags: perl, printf

My question has to do with arrays and `printf`.
Why doesn't the example below give me the expected output?
Is it because of the bash shell that does not interpret Perl correctly, or is it because Perl has changed syntax since my current version compared to the code syntax?

Or...Am I missing some parentheses, double quotes, etc...?

Is `printf` different in bash shell compared to Perl?
Or maybe has this to do with printf alone and not Perl and Bash specifically?

environment: Perl 5.34 in bash shell, linux

```
my @fruits = qw (apple pears dates);
printf "The fruits are : \n" .("%10s\n" x @fruits), @fruits;
```

My expected output :

```
The fruits are:
        apple 
        pears 
        dates
3
```

My output:

```
The fruits are:
    apple 
    pears 
    dates
```

Number 3, meaning the scalar context is omitted! Why?
My understanding so far:
This is scalar context to get its length and a list context to get its contents
And I am using the x operator, (.)concatenation, and (,) for list context + parentheses.

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_? There is no bash in your code.

Comment: Where do you expect the output of `3` should come from?

Comment: printf "The fruits are : "\n" .("10s\n" x @fruits), @fruits; the last , (comma)@fruits in the code

Comment: Your double quotes aren't balanced, and there's a missing semicolon; does that even run?

Comment: You have posted code that does not compile. You should never post code that is not *exactly* identical to the code you claim to have run. Otherwise you are just wasting people's time.

Comment: Also your "expected output" does not make sense. You are using the `x` operator to get `printf` to print all the fruit names. If this does not work, then your expected output would be `10s` 3 times. You cannot possibly be expecting a number 3 in the output.

Comment: `"abc" x @fruits` does not evaluate to in a number; it evaluates into a string.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, as posted:

```
my @fruits = qw (apple pears dates)
printf "The fruits are : "\n" .("10s\n" x @fruits), @fruits;
```

I get the following fatal error:

```
Backslash found where operator expected at foo.pl line 8, near ""The fruits are : "\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
String found where operator expected at foo.pl line 8, near "n" .(""
Number found where operator expected at foo.pl line 8, near "" .("10"
        (Missing operator before 10?)
syntax error at foo.pl line 8, near "printf"
Substitution pattern not terminated at foo.pl line 8.
```

So, you're not really running that code. Presumably your printf statement is actually working, which means you didn't have `10s`, but `%10s`, and your string multiplier `x` actually worked to duplicate it three times. And you did not have a missing semi-colon. And you cannot have extra double quotes that break the quoting. So we get:

```
my @fruits = qw (apple pears dates);
printf "The fruits are : \n" .("%10s\n" x @fruits), @fruits;
```

Which prints:

```
The fruits are :
     apple
     pears
     dates
```

I don't know where you think you get a number 3, or why you expect it. Nothing in your code does what you say it does.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and pointers. I typed it all by hand because I was on another machine and made unfortunately some error in judgment when I typed it. Now it looks as I run it on the virtual machine.I will think about copying it directly on the same machine another time.

Comment: @jok_sysswe You see the problems you get when your code is not exact. Troubleshooting becomes a guessing game, even though the code is simple.